# Error type 'Future<List<Object>>' is not a subtype of type 'List<Object>' in type cast

Tags: json, flutter, dart

I'm trying to create a list of objects - from [SpaceX](https://api.spacexdata.com/v2/launches) - where each object is a clickable link that leads to a details page, but I keep getting this error:

"type 'Future<List>' is not a subtype of type 'List' in type cast"

My Classes:

- main.dart: https://pastebin.com/EdxdM7GR
- MyApp.dart: https://pastebin.com/bzH0b73C (this is where the error is - I think)
- Launch.dart: https://pastebin.com/0aygjZm7 (mostly generated from app.quicktype.io, WARNING: 800+ lines of code, only included for completeness)
- Services.dart: https://pastebin.com/B4fKJywk

[Error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VIliQ.png)

More specifically, I believe the error comes from line 22, in MyApp.dart:

```
futureLaunch = fetchLaunch() as Future<Launch>;
```

since that's the only place I cast anything as anything... but I have no idea how to fix it. Every time I change it, I only wind up with new errors.

Attempted fixes:

- tried to follow [this walkthrough](https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/networking/fetch-data), which got me a bunch of new errors - once those were corrected, I was back at the same error.
- looked at 3 different stackoverflow questions/answers

  1. [type 'Future<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'List<dynamic>' in type cast](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57664327/type-futuredynamic-is-not-a-subtype-of-type-listdynamic-in-type-cast)
  2. [Getting this error - type 'Future<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'List<dynamic>'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57791206/getting-this-error-type-futuredynamic-is-not-a-subtype-of-type-listdynam)
  3. [Getting type 'List<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'List<...>' error in JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52886683/getting-type-listdynamic-is-not-a-subtype-of-type-list-error-in-json)

none of which managed to help.

- watched [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WOILEQTZtgY&ab_channel=LirsTechTips), which is where I found app.quicktype.io, but ultimately didn't help me solve the error.

Answer (score 1):

you have to await the list because it is a future list

Comment: But I do await... in MyApp I have "Services.getLaunches().then((list)", as I understand it, 'then' is roughly equivalent to await, right? and in main, I have "final http.Response response = await http.get('url);" and likewise in Services...

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the concrete error, this is caused because fetchLaunch() returns a `Future<List<Launch>>`, not a `Future<Launch>`.

Why do you load the list of Launches in 2 places, main.dart and Services.dart?
Right now you have a mix of using FutureBuilder and setState, this could be simplified a lot. Example (untested code, could contain errors):

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'SpaceX',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: FutureBuilder<List<Launch>>(
        future: Services.getLaunches(),
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          return Scaffold(
            appBar: AppBar(
              title: Text(snapshot.hasData ? 'Loading...' : 'SpaceX Launches'),
              centerTitle: true,
            ),
            body: Center(
              child: Builder(builder: (context) {
                if (snapshot.hasData) {
                  return Text(snapshot.data.first?.missionName ?? "No missions");
                } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
                  return Text('${snapshot.error}');
                }
                return CircularProgressIndicator();
              }),
            ),
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: "Why […] in 2 places? " I hadn't even noticed that; yes my code could definitely use some cleanup - I've just started just that :) "fetchLaunch() returns a Future<List<Launch>>, not a Future<Launch>" -- right, but no matter how I seem to change it, an error still occurs...